# Query MongoDB via PHP, compare date and send email

Tags: php, mongodb, email

I want to do a query over all users in my database. Check the 'lastLogin' of each user and if this is longer ago than e.g. 7 days, send a mail to the mail address of this user.
I did a simple query already, but I have no idea how to continue. The array notation really confuses me...

Hope somebody can help me out or even post a code snippet!

```js
<?php

$m = new Mongo();
$collection = $m->selectDB('platte')->selectCollection('users');

$results = $collection->find(array(),array("email"=>1, "lastLogin"=>2));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially looking for a range query. Create a **[`MongoDate`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php)**, for example using **[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**, that represents the date 7 days ago and use that in your search query for searching documents whose login field is less than the 7 days ago date:

In Mongo shell, this would be represented with the query:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);

var query = {
    "lastLogin": {
        "$lte": d
    }
};
var projection = {
    "email": 1,
    "lastLogin": 1
}

db.users.find(query, projection);
```

In PHP, this would translate to:

```
$m = new Mongo();
$collection = $m->selectDB('platte')->selectCollection('users');

$d = new MongoDate(strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s","-7 days")));
$searchCriteria = array(
    "lastLogin" => array(
        "$lte" => $d
    ),    
);
$projection = array(
    "email" => 1, 
    "lastLogin" => 1
);

$results = $collection->find($searchCriteria, $projection);
```